# There are positive integers $a,b,c$ such that $m^a=1+n^bc$

Tags: number-theory

Let  $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime integers and $m>1,n>1$. Show that:There are positive integers $a,b,c$ such that $m^a=1+n^bc$ , and  $n$ and $c$ are relatively prime

Comment: Is $c$ allowed to be $1$?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Well, $1$ is a positive integer and relatively prime to $n$, so yes.

Comment: I asked because it more or less trivializes the question. Consider the powers of $m$ modulo $n$, and bear in mind that since $m$ and $n$ are coprime one may divide by $m$ modulo $n$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri: Letting $c$ be $1$ is extremely restrictive - powers don't often differ by $1$. Maybe you're thinking of letting $b$ be $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I deleted the previous answer and replaced it with a simpler argument, although the idea is similar.

We know that $m^{\phi(n^2)}\equiv 1 \pmod{n^2}$, i.e.
$$m^{\phi(n^2)}=1+n^2z.$$
If $(n,z)=1$ we are done, otherwise we use the following lemma.

**Lemma**. If $p$ is a prime and $p|n$ then 
$$(1+n^2z)^p=1+n^2(pz)c$$
with $(c,n)=1$.

**Proof** 
$$(1+n^2z)^p=1+\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} {p\choose i}(n^2z)^i+n^{2p}z^p=1+pn^2z(1+Cn)$$
because $p|{p\choose i}$ for $1\leq i\leq p-1$ and $p|n$. Finally $(n,1+Cn)=1$.

Now thanks to the previous lemma we start "feeding" prime factors of $n$ to $z$ until we can factor out a power of $n$, and we are left with $1+n^ac$ and $(c,n)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, for any $b$ we have $m^{\phi(n^b)} \equiv 1 \mod{n^b}$, which is to say that there exists a $c$ such that $m^{\phi(n^b)} =
1+n^bc$.

Comment: Why is $c$ relatively prime to $n$?

Comment: An excellent question. There are two things we can tweak.  We can choose $b$ as we please, and having done so, if $r$ is the order of $m$ modulo $n^b$, we can choose any multiple of $r$ for $a$.  Last night I thought it was obvious how to tweak these two.  I seem to be dumber this morning.